# Getting a Modal pop form to show up in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

i'm trying to use the following code to open a Form using VBA

```
Private Sub cmdEdit_Click()
Dim d As New Form_EditNote
d.txtDate.Value = EntryDate.Value
d.txtNote.Value = Note.Value
d.Visible = True
End Sub
```

the form opens but only for a split second .. then goes away... any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring your variable `d`, assigning it to your form, you make the form visible, then your function is over and all your local variables are destroyed. Your form is one of these local variables. You need to use `DoCmd.OpenForm EditNote`. That will *keep* it open

To make it modal, either set the modal porperty to true at design time if you always want it to be modal. Or in [`DoCmd.OpenForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820845.aspx) set the `WindowMode` to `acDialog`

Comment: Your right of Course, (feeling stupid) .. But then I have another question .. in that How do I assign a callback of some sort in VBA? in other words, I have a module that opens the form.. passees data to it, then that sub ends .. and the form is still open .. how do I tell the form to return to the calling sub with the new data entered into the form? ( I know how to do this with C# .. but VBA is kicking my butt)

Comment: You want to know, in your parent form, when your child form has closed and do something in the parent form based on what happened in the child form?

Comment: This seems like it should probably be a new question entirely, but VBA does have the capacity to raise/listen to events. You can also call some function in the parent form in the Child `closed event`. That might not be a great solution depending on from how many places the child can be called.